# iOS popover how to remove the shade

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uipopovercontroller

Whenever we show popover the neighbhouring areas show different kind of gray color and the active tab bar icon color changes from blue to gray till pop over is there.

when the popover is dismissed , the grey shade gets removed

I would like to remove the color when the the popover is visible

I googled but I couldn't find anyway seems like this default behaviour.

any help to help me fix the problem is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For achieve this, you can create own custom popover background of `UIPopoverBackgroundView`.
you can find the below code for creating custom CustomPopoverBgView.

**CustomPopoverBgView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface CustomPopoverBgView : UIPopoverBackgroundView
{
    UIImageView *_borderImageView;
    UIImageView *_arrowView;
    CGFloat _arrowOffset;
    UIPopoverArrowDirection _arrowDirection;
}
@end
```

**CustomPopoverBgView.m**

```
#import "CustomPopoverBgView.h"
#define CONTENT_INSET 10.0
#define CAP_INSET 25.0
#define ARROW_BASE 25.0
#define ARROW_HEIGHT 25.0
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        _borderImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"popover-bg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET,CAP_INSET)]];

        _arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

        [self addSubview:_borderImageView];
        [self addSubview:_arrowView];
    }
    return self;
}
+(UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET, CONTENT_INSET);
}

+(CGFloat)arrowHeight{
    return ARROW_HEIGHT;
}

+(CGFloat)arrowBase{
    return ARROW_BASE;
}
- (CGFloat) arrowOffset {
    return _arrowOffset;
}

- (void) setArrowOffset:(CGFloat)arrowOffset {
    _arrowOffset = arrowOffset;
}
- (void)setArrowDirection:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirection {
    _arrowDirection = arrowDirection;
}
- (UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirection {
    return _arrowDirection;
}
@end
```

Calling of **`CustomPopoverBgView`** in `UIPopoverController`

```
 UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
 ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dddddd"];
 controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
 UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller] ;

 popoverController.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBgView class];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:btn.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:true];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing the code that demonstrates the usage of the custom background view.

Comment: How can I use this in place of popovercontroller ? Please explain me thanks

Comment: Thank you very much it works.I have missed allotting bounty to you sorry about that.the tab bar color turns into gray when popover is appearing .. is it possible to assign clearcolor for that too

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom popover view and add it as a subview on top of your main view instead of the default one Apple provided.

Comment: it will not look like popover right I mean on top of some other view.I mean other views has to be below the custom popover view

Comment: Yes, and that’s exactly why you need a shade to make it look like a popover view